# How to get an image in my Raster field to show up in the pop up?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, fields-attributes, popup

I am making a map of a neighborhood using GIS and ArcGIS Pro for the first time. I have a field in my lot feature for a raster to attach a picture of each lot to.

[image]

I can see the picture under my attributes tab but the pop up doesnt show it and when I try to add the images to the pop up through the configure pop ups tab the raster field isnt an option. What am I missing here?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hyperlink, lighting icon?

Comment: This is my first time using GIS software. So I dont know what lighting icon is. Whats the point of the raster field if it doesnt show the picture?

Comment: How did you put the picture into the field? Have a read of http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/imagery/adding-raster-datasets-as-attributes-in-a-feature-class.htm and see if that clears up some of your problem.

Comment: That is how I added the picture to the attribute.